# Firefox Nightly: cannot disable certificate validation for Service Workers

Tags: certificate, service-worker, firefox-nightly

I tried to disable certificate validation for service workers on Firefox Nightly setting:

```
dom.serviceWorkers.testing.enabled: true
dom.webnotifications.serviceworker.enabled: true
devtools.serviceWorkers.testing.enabled: true
dom.serviceWorkers.enabled: true
```

in `about:config` tab.

I restarted Firefox, but I still get an exception on ServiceWorking registration caused by user settings limitations.

What can I do more?